# Use of comparisons in objective function of an ILP

Tags: modeling, integer-programming

If the objective function of a problem contains a comparison between two linear statements, can the problem still be defined as an Integer Linear Program? For example:

$$\text{max} \sum_{\forall i,j} x_{i,j} - (y_{i,j}\cdot A_{i,j} \ge B_{i,j})$$
where $x_{i,j}$ and $y_{i,j}$ are binary variables, and $A_{i,j}$ and $B_{i,j}$ are constants.

Note: The value of $(y_{i,j}\cdot A_{i,j} \ge B_{i,j})$ should be 1 if it evaluates to true, 0 otherwise.

Comment: What is the outcome of $(A_{ij}y_{ij} \geq B_{ij})$? If this expression is satisfied, do you want to count it as a 1 or as a 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to introduce a helper variable (say $z_{ij}$) to count:

\begin{align}
\text{max }& \sum_{\forall i,j} x_{i,j} - z_{ij} &\\
\text{s.t. }& A_{i,j} y_{i,j} \leq B_{i,j} + Mz_{ij}&\forall i,j\\
&z_{ij}\in \{0,1\} &\forall i,j
\end{align}

Here $M$ is a sufficiently large number.

Comment: If $A_{i,j} y_{i,j} = B_{i,j}$, $z_{i,j}$ would need to be 1, but this formulation seems to yield $z_{i,j}=0$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @yucelf yes the border case of equality is a little tricky. You could change the equation to $A_{ij}y_{ij}\leq B_{ij}-\epsilon + Mz_{ij}$ where $\epsilon$ is a small number, e.g. $0.00001$.